# Uniform Continuity of sum of a series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$, where $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n(x-n+\frac1{n}),\ \ x\in[n-\frac1{n},n]\\n(n+\frac1{n}-x),\ \ x\in[n,n+\frac1{n}]\\0,\ \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then, is $f(x)$ uniformly continuous? I think no. But, I am unable to justify through rigour. By looking at the series of functions, I think it is pointwise convergent to zero. But, I dont think it is uniformly convergent. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: for your first question, what can you say about $f(n)-f(n+1/n)$? 
For your second question, what is $f(n+1)-\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}{f_k(n+1)}$?

Comment: so since $f(n)-f(n+\frac1{n})\to1$ as $n\to\infty$, therefore $f$ is not uniformly continuous. But, is the series uniformly convergent? I am unable to decipher the difference $f(n+1)-\sum_{1\le k\le n}f_k(n+1)$

Comment: What is $f_k(n+1)$ if $k < n$? What is $f_{n+1}(n+1)$?